# How do I perform a property level transform on an object in a type safe way?

Tags: typescript

Given the following types:

```
type Field<T> = {
  edited: boolean;
  value: T;
}

type Form = {
  name : Field
  location: Field
}
```

and corresponding object:

```
const form: Form = {
  name: { edited: false, value: 'Joe'},
  age: {edited: true, value: 32 }
};
```

I want to transform/project the object into the following form:

```
{
   name: 'Joe',
   age: 32
};
```

I have it working with the following code, but it is not type safe and it seems there is likely a more elegant solution:

```
function transform(form: Form) : Result{
  const keys = Object.keys(form);

  const keyValues = keys.map((key) => ({
      [key]: form[key].value // TODO form[key] and value are not typed
    }));
  
  const mergedObject = keyValues.reduce(
      (prev, curr) => ({ ...prev, ...curr }),
      {} 
    );

  return mergedObject as Result;
}
```

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-ts-transform?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the `transform` function in conjunction with [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)

```
function transform(form: Form): Result {
  function getValue(result: Result, k: keyof Form): Result {
    return { ...result, [k]: form[k].value };
  }

  return Object.keys(form).reduce(getValue, {} as Result);
}
```

This is pretty much the same as your answer though (with typing and a simplified transform function), there may be a better solution that uses more advanced typescript features.